# Chrome Webdriver can't interact with page elements when RDP is closed

Tags: selenium, rdp

I’m using the default “Remote desktop connection” of Windows to access an Azure virtual machine where I'm using Chrome Webdriver to upload a video on YouTube. The script works fine as long as the RDP is connected and video is uploaded but when I close the “Remote desktop connection” I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin23\Desktop\pip\SB\uploader.py", line 45, in <module>
    time.sleep(3)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\admin23\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 93, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Users\admin23\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 410, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\admin23\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 444, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\admin23\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 249, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=107.0.5304.122)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x0057ACD3+2075859]
    Ordinal0 [0x0050EE61+1633889]
    Ordinal0 [0x0040B680+571008]
    Ordinal0 [0x0043BBD6+768982]
    Ordinal0 [0x00431C76+728182]
    Ordinal0 [0x0045731C+881436]
    Ordinal0 [0x004315BF+726463]
    Ordinal0 [0x00457534+881972]
    Ordinal0 [0x0046B56A+963946]
    Ordinal0 [0x00457136+880950]
    Ordinal0 [0x0042FEFD+720637]
    Ordinal0 [0x00430F3F+724799]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0082EED2+2769538]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00820D95+2711877]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0060A03A+521194]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00608DA0+516432]
    Ordinal0 [0x0051682C+1665068]
    Ordinal0 [0x0051B128+1683752]
    Ordinal0 [0x0051B215+1683989]
    Ordinal0 [0x00526484+1729668]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x7695FEF9+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77937BBE+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77937B8E+238]
```

My Code (which works fine when RDP is Open):

```
import keyboard
from keyboard import press
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = Options()
options.page_load_strategy = "normal"
options.add_argument(r"--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\admin23\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\" )
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = options)
driver.get("https://studio.youtube.com")
time.sleep(4)
driver.find_element("xpath",'//*[@id="upload-icon"]/tp-yt-iron-icon').click()
time.sleep(3)
elem = driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="select-files-button"]').click()
time.sleep(3)
keyboard.write("file_I_want_to_upload")
press('enter')
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element("xpath",'//*[@id="next-button"]/div').click()
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element("xpath", '// *[ @ id = "text-container"] / div').click()
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element("xpath", '// *[ @ id = "radio-on"]').click()
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="save-button"]/div').click()
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element("xpath",'//*[@id="next-button"]/div').click()
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element("xpath", '// *[ @ id = "checkbox-container"]').click()
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="submit-questionnaire-button"]/div').click()
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element("xpath",'//*[@id="next-button"]/div').click()
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="next-button"]/div').click()
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="next-button"]/div').click()
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="privacy-radios"]/tp-yt-paper-radio-button[3]').click()
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element("xpath",'//*[@id="done-button"]').click()
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element("xpath", '// *[ @ id = "secondary-action-button"] / div').click()
#time.sleep(100)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Please show your code, not only the error notification

Comment: The code works fine when RDP is open but this is the error I get when RDP is closed. So i think it has got something to do with RDP GUI.

Comment: You already wrote that inside the question. I'm not sure, but maybe additional information will be useful

Comment: @Prophet I have added the code, please check.